# Crowdfunding citizen legislation?

Tags: civil-law

I'm a passionate citizen with an idea to stop the ill conceived CA highspeed rail act. I submitted the initiative to the CA Secretary of State but it was rejected because it's not actually a law - it needs to be written as a law. Submission here:
http://casmarthighway.tumblr.com/post/127581066937/official-submission-to-the-ca-attorney-general

OK, I get that. But now I need to make it a law. Does anyone know about how much legal time that would take? How much money I would need to raise from supporters/crowdsource? Would anyone on this site with some expertise in public policy want to help with the project?

Comment: Consult a lawyer; get a quote

Comment: So your proposal to kill the high-speed-rail is to impose a tax on cars for every mile they drive?

Answer (score 1):

California has a ballot initiative process that can be used to amend statute:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/California_ballot_proposition

The proposal would need to say what specific amendments to California statute would be made. i.e. What sections would be repealed, what sections would be added, what sections would be amended, etc.

Here's an example: https://ballotpedia.org/Text_of_Proposition_14,_the_Top_Two_Primaries_Act_(California_2010)